# How to input %% into a text file (with batch file)?

Tags: batch-file, input, windows-10, escaping, special-characters

This is a part of my code

```
echo for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b') do (>>test.bat
```

When I executed it, it input:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %A in ('dir /b') do (
```

into the 'test.bat' file.

I was expecting %%A to be input. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried doubling up the `%` yet?